# How to use distinct colors with Google GeoChart

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, google-visualization

I understand how to use the GeoChart to display a data that is in a continuum (i.e. temperture).

But how can you configure it to display distinct data sets (states that are republican, democratic, independent)?  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to use GeoChart in this way.  To accomplish this I ended up using a svg map, and changing the fill via css.

A good tutorial can be found here: http://blog.visual.ly/how-to-make-choropleth-maps-in-d3/

Answer (score 11):

You can also solve this by massaging the data a bit and using formatted values for your labels.  You should be able to paste the following code into [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart) to see an example:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var geoData= new google.visualization.DataTable();
  geoData.addRows(2);
  geoData.addColumn('string', 'State');
  geoData.addColumn('number', 'Votes (%)');

  geoData.setValue(0, 0, 'Alabama');
  geoData.setValue(0, 1, 0);
  geoData.setFormattedValue(0, 1, '56%');

  geoData.setValue(1, 0, 'Maine');
  geoData.setValue(1, 1, 1);
  geoData.setFormattedValue(1, 1, '64%');

  var options = {};
  options['region'] = 'US';
  options['resolution'] = 'provinces';
  options['colorAxis'] = { minValue : 0, maxValue : 1, colors : ['#FF0000','#0000FF']};
  options['backgroundColor'] = '#FFFFFF';
  options['datalessRegionColor'] = '#E5E5E5';
  options['width'] = 556;
  options['height'] = 347;
  options['legend'] = 'none';

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(geoData, options);
}
```

​

Answer (score 5):

This can now be accomplished by converting your classifications to numbers instead of party names.  For example:

```
democrats = 0
independents = 1
republicans = 2
```

Next include a color for each party in the colorAxis colors array:

```
var options = {
  colorAxis: {
    colors: ['blue','green','red']
    ...
  }
}
```

The following code displays democratic states as blue, republicans as red and independents as green (the data is made up, I don't which states prefer which party).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geochart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['State', 'Party'],
        ['US-NY', 0],
        ['US-AB', 2],
        ['US-TX', 2],
        ['US-CA', 0],
        ['US-AK', 2],
        ['US-MI', 1]
      ]);

      var options = {
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution:'provinces',
        colorAxis:{
          colors:['blue','green','red'],
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue:2},
       region:'US',
       legend:'none'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

     chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As long as the colors you list in the colorAxis match the number and order of classifications you use for the states, you can control the color of the state.

[image: sample map]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
data.addColumn('string', 'State');
data.addColumn('number', 'Votes (%)');
data.addColumn('string', 'Winner');
data.addRows([['Alabama', 56, 'Republicans'],['Maine', 61, 'Democrats']]);
```